# Python Script does not work but doesn't give errors either

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json, requests, sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)
print ("Delete all messages from specific channel")

username1 = "123"
username2 = "123"
auth_token = "123"
channel_id = "123"
delete_from_all_users = "False"

def get_all_messages(auth, id, last="", prev=[]):
    if not last:
        messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"limit": 100}).content)
    else:
        messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"before" : last, "limit" : 100}).content)

    prev = prev + messages

    if len(messages) < 100:
        print ("Got to end of channel at " + str(len(prev)) + " messages")
        return prev
    else:
        oldest = sorted(messages, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"], reverse=True)[-1]
        return get_all_messages(auth, id, last=oldest["id"], prev=prev)

def delete_all(auth, id, user1, user2, messages):
    print ("Trying to delete all messages in " + id + " from username " + user1)
    for message in messages:
        # print(message["author"]["username"])
        if (message["author"]["username"] == user1):
            requests.delete("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages/" + message["id"],headers={"authorization": auth})
    print ("All messages were deleted")

delete_all(auth_token, channel_id, username1, username2, get_all_messages(auth_token, channel_id))
```

This is the script that I got from someone on the internet, the section with "123" is originally replaced with some private information. I fixed few things to get this script to work, I resolved all the errors but the script itself just stopped working in general. I fixed a recursion error by adding "sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)" and I fixed a memory error by installing python 3.7 64bit (I had 32bit before). Now I run the script, after hours, it returns with no error and it does not do anything.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Retrieve all the messages in a discord channel and then erase all the messages from a specific user?

Comment: @Chris yeap! It works in channels with lower amount of messages and stops with no error on massive channels. I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You checked if there were messages by user `123` before you ran it, there were, and they are still there after running?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeap! All messaged were there, about 14k of them and still the same amount when I was finished running the script. I tried it on other channels and it works fine but it seems like channels with lots of messages does not work. I am not sure how to resolve this though, by adding which script? or allocating more memory resources? Not sure.because it gives me no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... this seems like a really, really poor use of recursion. It's hard to help without an example of the data you're trying to manipulate, but I'd replace the first part with the following:

```
def get_all_messages(auth, id, limit=100):
    messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + str(id) + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"limit": limit}).content)
    last = last_message_id(messages)
    n = len(messages)
    while n == limit:
        new_messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + str(id) + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"before" : last, "limit" : limit}).content)
        last = last_message_id(new_messages)
        n = len(new_messages)
        messages.extend(new_messages)
        print("Retrieved {n} messages [Total: {tot}]".format(n=n, tot=len(messages)))
    return messages

def last_message_id(mes):
    return sorted(mes, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"], reverse=True)[-1]["id"]
```

Again, without examples of the data you want to manipulate, it's difficult to know what the best way to write this would be.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the code I posted. It should have been messages.extend(), not messages.append(). It's corrected now.

Comment: Ideally you'd have an example of the JSON data that you're getting from the web server. It's hard to figure out how to work with data when the structure is unknown.